# Split tag vs. untag

Tags: discussion, tags

I've found a few questions that use the `squid` tag with a distinct meaning form the wiki tag (proxy server):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squid+sonar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squid+sonarqube

What should I do in order to improve SO?

1. Leave it as is
2. Create a new tag sonarsquid or squidsonar and retag questions
3. Simply remove squid tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the better option is #2 as it helps to have a properly defined list of questions for the other products named 'squid' - the 'squid' tag should have a description clarifying what it means by 'squid', and possibly linking to other relevant tags in the tag wiki

Arguably there should be different tags for each product called 'squid' and no use of a generic tag which is ambiguous but i think in this example most people would understand 'squid' to refer to the proxy server